# Proper names for SUM(col) fields

Tags: mysql, fields

I have worked on MySQL databases for a long time, but one question I have never been able to get an answer to that seemed formal is: In the query `SELECT *, SUM(col1) FROM tbl`, what is the proper name for the field `SUM(col1)`. The closest I have been able to determine is it is a computed column, is this correct or does it have another name?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL Documentation refers to the [**SUM() function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) as an ***aggregate or group function***. In light of this, I would call it an aggregated column since the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) starts with:

> This section describes group (aggregate) functions that operate on sets of values. Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.

As for the `CASE` statement, the [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892)

[image: sxcs]

page 82 paragraph 1 and pages 88-92 refers to `CASE` as a conditional control statement. Personally, I would call it a conditional control column or, simply, a conditional column.

Comment: I had seen that too, but when it comes to statements such as `CASE col WHEN IS NULL 0 ELSE col END`, would that still be called a group aggregate function?